# What makes my image look half as wide as intended?

Tags: racket, racket-student-languages

I am trying to place a vertically positioned rectangle and another object on an empty-scene using place-images in Beginning Student Language. However, when I run the function, the rectangle only takes up half the scene horizontally when its width is set equal to the width of the scene.

I checked what happens to my code using Stepper and found where the image-width halves but I do not know why. Probably it's to do with cons which I am not very familiar with.
[image: between these two steps the width halves]

Here's the full code:

```
(require 2htdp/image)

(define WIDTH 400)
(define HEIGHT 300)
(define HMAX 100)
(define SCENE (empty-scene WIDTH HEIGHT))

(define-struct vcham [x h c])
(define c (make-vcham 0 100 "white"))

(define (render ch)
  (place-images (list (rectangle (* 1 WIDTH (/ (vcham-h ch) HMAX)) 50 "solid" "maroon")
                      (rectangle 1 1 "solid" "blue"))
                (list (make-posn 0 0) (make-posn 20 20))
                SCENE))

(render c)
```

I have simplified this code as much as a I could, thus the 1×1 rectangle. I am also interested in elegant alternatives to implement this, but am most interested in finding out why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`place-images` is like `place-image` :

> Places image onto scene with its **center** at the coordinates (x,y)
>   and **crops the resulting image** so that it has the same size as
>   scene. The coordinates are relative to the top-left of scene.

you can change `(make-posn 0 0)` to `(make-posn 200 25)`, or try `place-images/align`

```
(define (render ch)
  (place-images/align (list (rectangle (* 1 WIDTH (/ (vcham-h ch) HMAX)) 50 "solid" "maroon")
                      (rectangle 1 1 "solid" "blue"))
                (list (make-posn 0 0) (make-posn 20 20))
                "left" "top" SCENE))
```